# Script to delete event by date

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a script for delete events for a specific date interval in a specific calendar

The script is:

```
function delete_events()



{
var calendarName = 'name@group.calendar.google.com';
// for month 0 = Jan, 1 = Feb etc
// below delete from Jul 13 2020 to Jul 18 2020
var fromDate = new Date("2023-4-21");
var toDate = new Date("2023-4-24");
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++){
    var ev = events[i];
    // show event name in log
    Logger.log(ev.getTitle()); 
    ev.deleteEvent();
 }
 }
```

But it doesn't work
The answer is
Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getEvents')
delete_events   @ Codice.gs:11

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteEventForThisDate(d) {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('id');
  const dt = new Date(d);
  const s = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
  const e = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + 1);
  cal.getEvents(s,e).forEach(e => e.deleteEvent());
}
```

Comment: HOw can I use this?

Comment: Where I insert the date I want to delete?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions